# Question About Proving The Countable Subadditivity of $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to[0,+\infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, nondecreasing, and right-continuous function that satisfies $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$. Define a function $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to[0,+\infty]$ by letting $\mu^*(A)$ be the infimum of the set of sums $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(F(b_n)-F(a_n))$, where $\{(a_n,b_n]\}$ rangers over the set of sequences of half-open intervals that cover $A$, in the sense that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n]$.

I need to prove the following:

> If $\{A_n\}$ is an infinite sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mu^*(\bigcup_nA_n)\leq\sum_n\mu^*(A_n)$.

I would like to precede in the following way:

> Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an arbitrary sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. If $\sum_n\mu^*(A_n)=+\infty$, then $\mu^*(\bigcup_nA_n) \leq \sum_n\mu^*(a_n)$ certainly holds. So suppose that $\sum_n\mu^*(A_n)<+\infty$, and let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive number. For each $n$ choose a sequence $\{(a_{n,i},b_{n,i}]\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that covers $A_n$ and satisfies
> \begin{align*}
>     \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(F(b_{n,i}) - F(a_{n,i})) < \mu^*(A_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}.
> \end{align*}
> If we combine these sequences into one sequence $\{(a_j,b_j]\}$, then the combined sequence satisfies
> \begin{align*}
>     \bigcup_nA_n \subseteq \bigcup_j(a_j,b_j)
> \end{align*}
> and
> \begin{align*}
>     \sum_j(F(b_j) - F(a_j)) < \sum_n\left(\mu^*(A_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}\right) = \sum_n\mu^*(A_n) + \epsilon.
> \end{align*}
> These relations, together with the fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, imply that $\mu^*(\bigcup_nA_n) \leq \sum_n\mu^*(A_n)$.

However, I feel that my description is not rigorous enough. Especially, I claimed the existence of a sequence $\{(a_{n,i},b_{n,i}]\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that covers $A_n$ and satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(F(b_{n,i}) - F(a_{n,i})) < \mu^*(A_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$. However, I have difficulties construct a concrete sequence to show that this is indeed true. Here is some of my thought:

> Define a sequence $\{(c_{n,k},d_{n,k}]\}$ of half-open intervals such that $\bigcup_k(c_{n,k},d_{n,k}] = \bigcup_i(a_{n,i},b_{n,i}]\backslash A_n$ and that $d_{n,k} = c_{n,k}+p_{n,k}$, where $\{p_{n,k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of positive number converging to $0$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $F(d_{n,k}) - F(c_{n,k}) = F(c_{n,k}+p_{n,k}) - F(c_{n,k}) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}$. Note that such a sequence $\{p_{n,k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ exists due to the right-continuity of $F$. Then
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(F(b_{n,i}) - F(a_{n,i})) &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(F(d_{n,k}) - F(c_{n,k})) + \inf\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(F(b_{n,i}) - F(a_{n,i}))\right)\\
> &< \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} + \mu^*(A_n).
> \end{align*}

I seriously doubt that my attempt is entirely correct and rigorous. But this is really the best I can get. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check my construction and correct my proof if there is any flaws!

*Reference: Measure Theory 2nd Edition by Donald L. Cohn Proposition 1.3.10.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu^{*}$ by definition is the infimum of that set, so you can take an element from that set which is smaller than $\mu^{*}+\epsilon$